# How can I select 1 Radio button at a time which is used inside the Gridview

Tags: asp.net

I am binding the data to gridview like below. here I need to select 1 radion button at a time for each group. how to achive this in gridview

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try using `name` property of the radio button
Or you can set the `GroupName="group"` property of the radio button

Reference 
[how to use radio buttons in grid view in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163421/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-grid-view-in-asp-net)

More Tutorial

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/krishnasarala/select-single-radio-button-in-gridview-in-Asp-Net/

### Edit 1

As the above tutorial suggested

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="AuthId">
   <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbauthid" runat="server" 
             onclick="javascript:CheckOtherIsCheckedByGVID(this);" />
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="AUTHOR NAME" DataField="AuthName" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="AUTHOR LOCATION" DataField="AuthLocation" />
   </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

And create a java-script function as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckOtherIsCheckedByGVID(spanChk) {
            var IsChecked = spanChk.checked;
            if (IsChecked) {
                spanChk.parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = '#228b22';
                spanChk.parentElement.parentElement.style.color = 'white';
            }
            var CurrentRdbID = spanChk.id;
            var Chk = spanChk;
            Parent = document.getElementById("<%=GridView1.ClientID%>");
            var items = Parent.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if (items[i].id != CurrentRdbID && items[i].type == "radio") {
                    if (items[i].checked) {
                        items[i].checked = false;
                        items[i].parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
                        items[i].parentElement.parentElement.style.color = 'black';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: GroupName is not working inside the gridview. it generates different groupname for diffrent rows

Comment: Its working fine. However I am able to check 1 Radio button for Entire gridview. here I have 2 groups. one from each group. thanks anyway